# hibernate mapping list <Integer>

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

How can i map a list of integers in Hibernate? 
List <**Integer**> listMonth =new ArrayList <**Integer**> ();

Best regards.

Jirari Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

Use @ElementCollection mapping to achieve the purpose. See this for further details http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5405